# How to convert element from string to Array

Tags: xml, xslt

Here’s the XML I am currently playing with.

```
`
<ns2:FlightSummary Version="5.0.0" xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns2:FlightSummary ID="JXXK2019" PartitionID="FLS" SequenceNmbr="3" TimeStamp="2019-08-13T09:55:18.381" HasInvoices="false" UpdateTimeStamp="2019-08-13T09:55:18.070"/>
    <ns:GetReservationRS>
        <ns:Reservation>
            <ns:Reservation>
                <ns:Segments>
                    <ns:PoA>
                        <ns:Airport>NRT</ns:Airport>
                        <ns:Departure>2019-08-13T09:25:00</ns:Departure>
                    </ns:PoA>
                    <ns:Segment sequence="1" id="15">
                        <ns:Air sequence="1" DayOfWeekInd="2">
                            <ns:DepartureAirport>NRT</ns:DepartureAirport>
                            <ns:ArrivalAirport>TPE</ns:ArrivalAirport>
                            <ns:OperatingAirlineCode>JL</ns:OperatingAirlineCode>
                            <ns:OperatingAirlineShortName>JAPAN AIRLINES</ns:OperatingAirlineShortName>
                            <ns:OperatingFlightNumber>5045</ns:OperatingFlightNumber>
                            <ns:EquipmentType>ERD</ns:EquipmentType>
                            <ns:MarketingAirlineCode>JL</ns:MarketingAirlineCode>
                            <ns:MarketingFlightNumber>5045</ns:MarketingFlightNumber>
                            <ns:DepartureDateTime>2019-08-13T09:25:00</ns:DepartureDateTime>
                            <ns:ArrivalDateTime>2019-08-13T12:10:00</ns:ArrivalDateTime>
                            <ns:FlightNumber>5045</ns:FlightNumber>
                        </ns:Air>
                    </ns:Segment>
                </ns:Segments>
            </ns:Reservation>
        </ns:Reservation>
    </ns:GetReservationRS>
</ns2:FlightSummary>
`
```

Sometimes the segment element may contain more than one segment, in this case, the incoming XML shows the data in Array. At times I may have only one value and the data is shown as a string instead of Array. To add to this at times the XML message may not contain any data for segments, in this case, data is shown as `<ns:Segments/>` .

How to convert element from string to Array?
I am playing with the following XSLT to convert string to an array, however, I do not think its right as it displays the data as-is.

```
``
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:json="http://json.org/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array" 
version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name(..) = 'ns:Segment'">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="json:force-array">True</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>``
```

Comment: It would help you to get some answers if you post XML input and desired output.